# Json to csv. How to convert it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm experiencing some troubles to convert a Json (with nested values) to a CSV file (I want the headers at first line and the json values below). 
I almost did it but I still have some issues in my output.
I wrote everything I've done so far hoping that would make the task easier for you.

Here's the json :

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "email": "colleengriffith@quintity.com",
    "tags": [
             "consectetur",
             "quis"
    ],
    "profiles": {
      "facebook": {
        "id": 0,
        "picture": "//fbcdn.com/a2244bc1-b10c-4d91-9ce8-184337c6b898.jpg"
      },
      "twitter": {
        "id": 0,
        "picture": "//twcdn.com/ad9e8cd3-3133-423e-8bbf-0602e4048c22.jpg"
      }
    }
  },
      {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "maryellengriffin@ginkle.com",
    "tags": [
             "veniam",
             "elit",
             "mollit"
    ],
    "profiles": {
      "facebook": {
        "id": 1,
        "picture": "//fbcdn.com/12e070e0-21ea-4663-97d0-46bc9c7b67a4.jpg"
      },
      "twitter": {
        "id": 1,
        "picture": "//twcdn.com/3057792f-5dfb-4c4b-86b5-cce4d6bbf7ac.jpg"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and the ouput I want :

```
id,email,tags,profiles.facebook.id,profiles.facebook.picture,profiles.twitter.id,profiles.twitter.picture
0,colleengriffith@quintity.com,"consectetur,quis",0,//fbcdn.com/a2244bc1-b10c-4d91-9ce8-184337c6b898.jpg,0,//twcdn.com/ad9e8cd3-3133-423e-8bbf-0602e4048c22.jpg
1,maryellengriffin@ginkle.com,"veniam,elit,mollit",1,//fbcdn.com/12e070e0-21ea-4663-97d0-46bc9c7b67a4.jpg,1,//twcdn.com/3057792f-5dfb-4c4b-86b5-cce4d6bbf7ac.jpg
```

Here's what I came up to so far :

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'
require 'set'

def get_recursive_keys(hash, nested_key=nil)
  hash.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),keys|
    k = "#{nested_key}.#{k}" unless nested_key.nil?
      if v.is_a? Hash
      keys.concat(get_recursive_keys(v, k))
    else
      keys << k
    end
  end
end

json = JSON.parse(File.open("live.json").read)
headings = Set.new
json.each do |hash|
  headings.merge(get_recursive_keys(hash))
end

CSV.open('file3.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << headings
  json.each do |hash|
    row = {}
    headings.each do |heading|
      row[heading] = nil
    end
    hash.each do |k,v|
      row[k] = v.to_s.gsub(/\r\n?/, "").delete("\n").delete("\r")
    end
    csv << row.values
  end
end
```

When I run, I get this :

```
id,email,tags,profiles.facebook.id,profiles.facebook.picture,profiles.twitter.id,profiles.twitter.picture
0,colleengriffith@quintity.com,"[""consectetur"", ""quis""]",,,,,"{""facebook""=>{""id""=>0, ""picture""=>""//fbcdn.com/a2244bc1-b10c-4d91-9ce8-184337c6b898.jpg""}, ""twitter""=>{""id""=>0, ""picture""=>""//twcdn.com/ad9e8cd3-3133-423e-8bbf-0602e4048c22.jpg""}}"
1,maryellengriffin@ginkle.com,"[""veniam"", ""elit"", ""mollit""]",,,,,"{""facebook""=>{""id""=>1, ""picture""=>""//fbcdn.com/12e070e0-21ea-4663-97d0-46bc9c7b67a4.jpg""}, ""twitter""=>{""id""=>1, ""picture""=>""//twcdn.com/3057792f-5dfb-4c4b-86b5-cce4d6bbf7ac.jpg""}}"
```

So I do have everything I need, however, I still have the bracket and the quote and I want to remove them from the csv file.

If anyone has an idea or a tip, that would be great !

Any help appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set` is explicitly documented to be unordered so you should convert your headings to an `Array` as soon as you've populated it. Yes, the current standard implementation is ordered but you're better off avoiding implementation-dependent assumptions. So the first step is to make sure `headings` is guaranteed to have a consistent order before we do anything with it:

```
headings = headings.to_a
CSV.open('file3.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  ...
end
```

Then you just need to fix up how you encode arrays and hashes on their way into the CSV. You can use [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig) to find the nested values you want and then patch up any arrays that come out with a simple [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) call:

```
json.each do |hash|
  row = headings.map do |h|
    v = hash.dig(*h.split('.'))       # Dig out the (possibly) nested value
    v.is_a?(Array) ? v.join(',') : v  # Fix up arrays
  end
  csv << row
end
```

We're still making some assumptions (no commas in `"tags"`, no periods in the JSON keys, ...) of course.

---

You could also store the headers as arrays so that you don't have to `split` all the time. Then you'd need to throw a `join('.')` in when building your header row:

```
add_dots = ->(a) { a.join('.') }
csv << headings.map(&add_dots)
```

and just splat the arrays when building `v`:

```
v = hash.dig(*h)
```

and adjust `get_recursive_keys` to work with arrays rather than period delimited strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I've tried the first solution and it seems to work perfectly. Never heard about the dig method by the way. Clearly helpful !

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a gem. Which makes your things easier. Why reinvent the wheel?.

```
gem install json2csv
```

Refer [here](https://github.com/korczis/json2csv) for more details

Comment: Yup I know. But I need to get the output without any gems.